# How to set a UItextfield text in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I want to set the text for my UITextField using xctest

```
app.textFields["enter "].tap()
app.textFields["enter "].text = "xyz"
```

but its throwing error and I am not finding any alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
app.textFields["enter "].typeText("xyz")
```